# Разницы мобильных браузеров Chrome и Firefox и как исправить.Position fixed

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет.Я новичок в сайтостроении. Недавно создал свой первый статический сайт. Все нормально и стабильно работало пока я не загрузил сайт в своем мобильнике. Проблема первая заключается в том, что если зайти в мобильную версию в ПК в хроме (с шириной `480` пикселей), то все работает стабильно, нет никаких глюков. Но если зайти через смартфон в сайт, то все показывает не так как в мобильной версии браузера `Chrome` в ПК. Проблема заключается  в основном в `position:fixed`. Хедер сначала должен быть `65` пикселей, потом при скролле вниз он должен менять свой размер на `37` пикселей. В смартфоне в браузере `Firefox` все работает отлично. Но в `Chrome` если листать вниз, то хедер глючит, а потом прилипает тупо вверх и даже если скроллить до самого верха, то все равно хедер не возвращается в свой первоначальный размер (`65` пикселей). Плюс ко всему в хроме в, отличие от фаерфокса в самом низу появляется огромный белый  отступ,  при том, что в коде все в порядке. Помогите пожалуйста.Вот мой сайт http://heshimovnotes.com/

```
.menu {
    background: white;
    height: 65px;
}
.menu.sticky {
    height: 37px;
    max-width: 480px;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

И `JQuery`:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
      } 
      else {
        $('.menu').removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Попробуйте поставить вместо `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20)` 
 вот это: `if($(this).scrollTop() > $(".menu").clientHeight)`

Comment: @EugenEray спасибо но не помогло